# WMQ Client stops mq get without throwing any exception

Tags: .net, ibm-mq, mq

I have a windows service which listens to the MQ queue manager and get messages. There was a network interuption and MQ .Net client stopped listening to MQ Queue. They was no exception thrown by the application. So when i saw the event logs there was a error

> Process(1612.3) User(SYSTEM) Program(MMQ.Receiver.exe) Host(*****) Installation(Installation1) VRMF(7.5.0.4)
>
> Error on receive from host .
>
> An error occurred receiving data from  over TCP/IP. This may be due to a communications failure.
>
> The return code from the TCP/IP (socket.Receive) call was 10054 (X'2746'). Record these values and tell the systems administrator.

And the MQ client file has the same above error with the below line.

> IBM.WMQ.MQTCPConnection.Receive

How should i handle these type of error. As i said there was no error thrown in the code.Below is my code

```
try
            {
                if (queuereceive == null)
                {                        
                    RetryConnection();
                }
                else
                {
                    inboundmsg = new MQMessage();                        
                    queuereceive.Get(inboundmsg, queueGetMessageOptions);

                    //code where it receives the message and do the process 

                    inboundmsg.ClearMessage();
                }
            }
            catch (MQException mqe)
            {
                inboundmsg = null;
                if (mqe.Reason == MQC.MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)
                {

                }
                else if (mqe.Reason == MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_QUIESCING || mqe.Reason == MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN)
                {
                    if (queueManagerreceive != null)
                    if (queueManagerreceive.IsConnected)
                    {
                        queueManagerreceive.Disconnect();
                    }

                    RetryConnection(); //retire connection if an exception is thrown 
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Error(string.Format("MQQueue::Get ended with {0} ", mqe.Message));
                    if (queueManagerreceive != null)
                    if (queueManagerreceive.IsConnected)
                    {
                        queueManagerreceive.Disconnect();
                    }

                    // treat truncated message as a failure 
                    if (mqe.Reason == MQC.MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED)
                    {
                        Logger.Error(string.Format("MQQueue::Get ended with {0}  ", mqe.Message));
                    }

                    RetryConnection(); //retire connection if an exception is thrown 
                }
            }
```

Note: RetryConnection reconnects to the MQ queue

Answer (score 0):

Try adding logging into the connection broken exception handling case. I think your client application is just getting thrown an MQException of type MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN - in which case your code silently disconnects and reconnects.  (Note 10054 usually means the other end has decided to close the connection which would tie up here if there was a network issue)

Comment: in my code it throws the exception and try to reconnect until it succeeds and i have the logging too i just deleted in this code. But in this case there was no exception thrown from the service i found that error in the event logs what should be the case for that?

Comment: is there a way to increase the default reconnect timeout(which is 30 min) on MQ client?

Comment: What do you mean by a 30min reconnect timeout. Once the connection is broken you should be able to retry making the connect. If the issue is the original connection is still appearing on the server locking resources the new connection needs, consider whether you are sharecnv>0 and using HBINT (MQv7 clients+), or alternatively needing to use keepalive (although that defaults to 2 hours).

Comment: when there is a network interruption the client is waiting for 30 min to reconnect and after that is throwed an exception  MQRC_RECONNECT_ENDED. am talking about that 30 min timeout